# Gaining insight on TCP traffic

Tags: macos, networking, tcp

I have an iMac on which I turned off almost all applications. Browser, Skype, Spotify all turned off. Despite that, when I do a `tcpdump` I record still a lot of TCP traffic.

How can I get insight into where this traffic is originating? Which applications or processing are involved?

Comment: Have you looked at the output of `netstat -pn`?

Comment: @NathanC: netstat: n: unknown or uninstrumented protocol

Comment: so capture that traffic and analyze it with wireshark

Comment: Try just `netstat -n`. Apparently it differs from *nix style.

Comment: Mac's netstat -p doesn't give processes (nor does there seem to be an equivalent), but is to specify protocol type, hence the error.  netstat -anptcp  will give all TCP sockets in use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see what processes are currently bound to TCP sockets in Mac OS X (10.8), one can use `lsof  -itcp` which will provide a list of open files(network connections are represented as special file types) and the process ID that is bound to the open socket.  Currently on my system:

```
[mini-nevie:~] nevinwilliams% lsof -itcp
COMMAND     PID          USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
WebProces 91698 nevinwilliams   27u  IPv4 0x902ab8abaca8b3f9      0t0  TCP 192.168.2.11:51499->stackoverflow.com:http (ESTABLISHED)
WebProces 91698 nevinwilliams   43u  IPv4 0x902ab8abb8727269      0t0  TCP 192.168.2.11:51475->stackoverflow.com:http (ESTABLISHED)
```

Note that this listing gives me the port name (found in /etc/services) instead of the number, which is useful in itself to help identify the kind of traffic.  Use `lsof -Pitcp` for numerical listing.

I see that one process with an ID of 91698 has two web connections to stackoverflow.com...

To get full process information on PID 91695, I can use `ps -f -p91698` ...

```
mini-nevie:~] nevinwilliams% ps -f -p91698
  UID   PID  PPID   C STIME   TTY           TIME CMD
  501 91698 91695   0 12:41am ??        26:05.50 /System/Library/StagedFrameworks/Safari/WebKit2.framework/WebProcess.app/Contents/MacOS/WebProcess /System/Library/StagedFrameworks/Safari/WebKit2.framework/WebKit2 -type webprocess -servicename com.apple.WebKit.WebProcess-91695-0x10d7011e0 -localization en_US
```

which tells me it's part of the Safari framework, obviously because I'm connected to the site with Safari as I write this.

For more information on `netstat`, `lsof`, and `ps`, see their respective `man` pages.